# How to get listitem id when I click on PopUp menu item?

Tags: android, android-layout, popupmenu

In my application I have attached popup menu with each item in listview. The popup menu has further two items when we click on popup menu icon.I have implemented `OnMenuItemClickListener` in my activity to listen for popup menu item clicks which is working fine.But the problem is that How do I get to know the listitem id (not popup menu item id) when I click on popup menu icon for any listview item.The popup menu code is below:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
        popup.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_play:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you call showPopup?

Comment: @pskink In my xml file from imageview onclick event

Comment: Ok... so your question is not really about "How to store some value and read it in onMenuItemClick callback" but rather "I've created onClick attrubire from xml and don't know how to get id of the parent list item view"? The PopupMenu has nothing to do with this issue at all, right?

Comment: Yes you are right @MaciejCiemięga

Comment: First of all: why on earth do you need to have id of the view? If you want to play something from the list you'd rather need a position to obtain item from the list related with this position.
Second: Do not use onClick event from xml while making a list... set OnClickListener in your adapter instead - there you will have your <b>int position</b> (or list item view's id if you really want it).
And please update your question, because it really is about completely different thing.

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga I am really sorry for misunderstanding but I need position not the id

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga For listitem click event I am using adapter but not for popup menu which I have attached with each listItem.

Comment: 1. Please post code for your adapter. 2. Do you want the handle "onMenuItemClick" in adapter, activity, fragment or it is not important for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please tell me what is "**listitem id**" that you want to know? I doubt that it's a "**listitem view's id**". Probably you're thinking about "**position**", right?

I don't know where do you call **showPopup(View v)** from, but you also need to pass the position there:

```
public void showPopup(View v, int listItemPosition) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
    popup.show();
}
```

Your goal is to know this position in the **onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)** callback.
The simplest way to achieve this is to create variable "listItemPositionForPopupMenu", store this position there and read it in the **onMenuItemClick** callback:

```
private int listItemPositionForPopupMenu;

public void showPopup(View v, int listItemPosition) {
    listItemPositionForPopupMenu = listItemPosition;
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
    popup.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_play:
            // read the listItemPositionForPopupMenu here
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

You can also do it in many other ways, like creating you own **OnMenuItemClickListener** listener with **listItemPosition** variable in constructor and create custom interface with **onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item, int listItemPosition)**. Or you can just create an anonymous class, then you don't need to have the **listItemPositionForPopupMenu** member variable:

```
public void showPopup(View v, final int listItemPosition) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_play:
                    // read the listItemPosition here
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
    popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: My question is how do I get the value of listItemPosition when I click on popup menu icon?You are passing listItemPosition  to showPopup method but I do not have value to pass to this method.I need the value

Comment: I've updated my answer to store list item view's id instead of position.

Comment: I have tried your code but id value I got is "-1" for every item in listview.

Comment: Yes, please see my comment to your question.

Comment: I've rolled back my comment to first version showing how to store list item position. It's all you need to resolve your issue with PopupMenu. To resolve your other issues: set OnClickListener from adapter (not onClick from xml) and in this listener invoke showPopup(View v, final int listItemPosition) method passing also position here.

Comment: Thanks @Maciej I have moved my code to adapter and I am now able to access the position easily.Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Please also do not forget to accept this answer if it was helpful for your problem.